# Importing GPS bird tracker text file and i want to display attributes

Tags: qgis, text

I am importing GPS bird tracker data with a cut down file consisting of

- Date/time.
- Lat/Long.
- Speed.

I would like the points to display with the speed as text.  Is this possible, if so how?

I'm using QGIS Madeira (3.4).

Comment: it is called a **label**.

Comment: Thank you JGH.  I'm sorry but I'm new to QGIS and would like to know how I apply the label to my data.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#labels-properties  There are also more tutorials available online like https://www.igismap.com/how-to-do-layer-labeling-in-qgis-3-2-1-use-and-change-label/

Comment: Thank you for response JGH, did a search on "label" in QGIS help (as I should have done in the first place) and found the answer in the label toolbar.  Some more experimentation and now nicely labelled with the speed.